# Group of units of $\mathbb F_p[x]/(x^3-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, field-theory

> Consider the ring $R=\mathbb F_p[x]/(x^3-1)$. Find the group of units (as a product of cyclic groups)
>    for $p=29,\ 31$.

We have $x^3-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$. If I manage to prove that the ideals $(x-1)$ and $(x^2+x+1)$ are comaximal in $\mathbb F_p[x]$, then it will follow by the Chinese remainder theorem that $R\simeq\mathbb F_p[x]/(x-1)\times \mathbb F_p[x]/(x^2+x+1)$. I don't see how I can obtain $1$ as a linear combination of these generators, so the first question is *how to show they are comaximal*?

Secondly,  $\mathbb F_p[x]/(x-1)\simeq \mathbb F_p$, and the answer depends on the second factor. It is a pain to check whether $x^2+x+1$ has a root for $p=29,\ 31$, so I was wondering *how to find roots of the polynomials quickly or prove that they are irreducible*?

Comment: Because $x^2+x+1\mid x^3-1$ any root has multiplicative order three (or one but we can ignore that). Because the multiplicative group of $\Bbb{F}_p$ is cyclic of order $p-1$ there is such an element in the field iff $3\mid p-1$. Meaning that $x^2+x+1$ factors modulo $31$ but is irreducible modulo $29$.

Comment: And a hint for comaximality: run the generalized Euclidean algorithm on $x-1$ and $x^2+x+1$ to find polynomials $u(x),v(x)$ such that $u(x)(x+1)+v(x)(x^2+x+1)$ is a constant. If the constant is non-zero you can check that it isn't divisible by either of the choices of $p$. Good luck!

Comment: It is, in fact, extremely easy to find a root of $x^2+x+1$ for $p=31$. What squares are closest to $31$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Regarding the first part, why can we ignore that a root of $x^2+x+1$ may have order one? For the second part, I got that $(x^2+x+1)-(x+2)(x-1)=3$. Did you mean that from this I can conclude that since $3$ is nonzero in either field and any non-zero element is invertible, hence $(x-1)+(x^2+x+1)=\mathbb F_p[x]$?

Comment: I guess we can ignore that a root of $x^2+x+1$ may have order one because if it does, then $x=1$, but $1+1+1\ne 3$ unless $p=3$.

Comment: Here is another way to see that the ideals are comaximal without getting your hands dirty with explicit calculations: you already know that $(x-1)$ is a maximal ideal, because when you quotient it out, you get the field $\mathbb F_p$. Since $(x-1) \subseteq (x-1)+(x^2+x+1)$, the comaximality follows if we show $(x-1) \subsetneq (x-1)+(x^2+x+1)$. Suppose otherwise, so $(x^2+x+1)\subseteq (x-1)$, which is equivalent to $x-1$ divides $x^2+x+1$, which implies that $1$ is a root of $x^2+x+1$, which can't be true because $p \neq 3$.

Comment: Yup. You got it. $x=1$ is a zero only when $p=3$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is it sufficient to note (instead of proving comaximality) that the two polynomials are coprime? I think I saw this version of the Chinese remainder theorem somewhere, but couldn't find this version online.

Comment: Yes. That suffices. Because a polynomial ring over a field is a Euclidean domain (hence a PID and a UFD) that is enough.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks! Could you clarify (or give a reference on) how the fact that $F[x]$ is a Euclidean doman/PID/UFD implies that it suffices to prove the polynomials are coprime?